# equalize distance when using \\ in LaTeX

Tags: spacing, packages, margins, enumerate, itemize

When I write a text after an `\end{itemize}` the distance is different when I use \. How can I equalize these distances?

````
\item Soporte de audio MP3
\item Permite crear animaciones interpoladas
\end{itemize} 

\textit{Herramientas de trabajo}\\

La interfaz de \textit{Adobe Animate CC} incluye paneles para
trabajar con el color, las acciones, las capas, los```
````

[image]

Comment: you have not provided a full example but you surely get a warning about the mis-placed `\\ ` ? never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! You put a newline after the `\\`, try deleting the new line and compile again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the length `\parskip` and use the `enumitem` package to customize the list likewise.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{3ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

La interfaz de \textit{Adobe Animate CC} incluye paneles para
trabajar con el color, las acciones, las capas, los fotogramas el audio, las imágenes y las instancias.


\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=\parskip,parsep=0ex,partopsep=0ex]   
\item Soporte de audio MP3
\item Permite crear animaciones interpoladas
\end{itemize}   

\textit{Herramientas de trabajo}

La interfaz de \textit{Adobe Animate CC} incluye paneles para
trabajar con el color, las acciones, las capas, los fotogramas el audio, las imágenes y las instancias.

\textit{Adobe Animate CC} permite el uso de bibliotecas para ..

\end{document}
```

Leave a blank line to start a new paragraph.